# How do you add Slack Integration to elastic cloud's keystore

Tags: elasticsearch, integration, slack

I am attempting to add slack integration to my elasticsearch instance, via adding a slack webhooks. I know that before version 7.0 I was able to put in my elasticsearch.yml file:

```
xpack.notification.slack:
   account:
     monitoring:
       url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0A6BLEEA/B0A6D1PRD/XYZ123
```

However, now I have to use this "secure keystore", and the syntax seems to be a little more complicated. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to this, the secure keystore is a little hard to find.

1. In https://cloud.elastic.co/home, navigate to your deployment
2. On the left side, under your deployment name, click on Security
   3.Here you will see a panel that says: Elasticsearch Keystore, where you can look at your current K-V pairs and also create new one

There you can add a slack webhook:

```
Key = xpack.notification.slack.account.<account_name>.secure_url
Values = the webhook URL
```

Hope that helps the next person with the same question!

Comment: is <account_name> an actual slack account? Or is it just an identifier that elastic uses for the web hook?

Comment: @Matt I was also looking for this, it seems it is the name/identifier that you give in your elasticloud setup : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions-slack.html